# if $S$ has an accumulation point $A$ then A is also an accumulation point for at least one of the sets $S\cap (-\infty, A]$ or $S\cap [A,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

if $S$ has an accumulation point $A$ then A is also an accumulation point for at least one of the sets $S\cap (-\infty, A]$ or $S\cap [A,\infty)$

I am not asking for anyone to just write out a proof...

Looking for methodology to proving this, and useful hints. Thanks.

Comment: Spelling out the definition of accumulation point should already get you most of the way

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have 6 different definitions of acc point. Which definition are you thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you proceed by contrapositive. Take an arbitrary point $a$ and set $S$ such that $a$ is an accumulation point of neither $S\cap(-\infty,a]$ nor $S\cap[a,\infty)$. Show that it isn't an accumulation point of $S,$ then, either. Bear in mind that the intersection of two open neighborhoods of $a$ is again an open neighborhood of $a$.

**Added**: I am thinking of the following definition when I make this recommendation.

> If $E\subseteq R$ and $x\in\Bbb R,$ we say that $x$ is an *accumulation point* of $E$ if for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a point $y\in U\cap E$ such that $y\ne x.$

An easier one to work with, though, is the following equivalent definition.

> If $E\subseteq R$ and $x\in\Bbb R,$ we say that $x$ is an *accumulation point* of $E$ if for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, the set $(U\cap E)\cup\{x\}$ has more than one point.